# visual studio solidity extension for solidity >0.4

Tags: solidity

I would like to know if the visual studio extension for solidity supports the release after **0.4**, I think this extension is only for previous releases **<= 0.3.5** while it was updated for the last time at 6/19/2016, is there any new update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a wide search about the subject. Indeed there is no update of the
[extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ConsenSys.Solidity) (Version 1.1.4.0 ) developed by ConsenSys.